# Horizontal ordered list

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to display an ordered list horizontally **with numbers**. Is it possible to do this without a script? When using `display: inline-block` the numbers seem to disappear:

```css
li { 
  display: inline-block 
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using anything other than `list-item` in your `display` property, the numbering goes off, but you can use `counter` to get it back.

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: list-c;
}
ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  counter-increment: list-c;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(list-c) '.';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k5u8ozes/1/

Also you should clear your floats and set some `margin-right`.